# Why do I get an error trying to use pytesseract?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

import pytesseract
import  PIL
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

Im trying that code alone with many other ways to type the pile path as in double '\' etc but I still continue to get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Answer (score 1):

In shell, run:

```
pip install Pillow
```

The error means you are missing some modules.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)
This is why im confused,  does it not work on latest python or something?

Comment: You should get some other errors if this is the case.

Comment: I would recommend you to check if your environment is in the correct setting

Comment: yea it just doesnt let me add the entire error..
   25 from packaging.version import parse
     26 from packaging.version import Version
---> 27 from PIL import Image
     30 tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'
     32 numpy_installed = find_loader('numpy') is not None
all the imports are giving an error but they all just seemed to bepointing at an issue with pillow but idk...

Comment: How do I check my environment setting and what should it be. Python noobie here.

Comment: An easy way to duel with environment is to use virtualenv. [Here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) is same good example to setup.

Comment: I dont know what to do :P

Comment: pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow fixed everything!!!!

Comment: That means your Pillow is not in the right version b4, but congrat ay.

Comment: im lost again, when i go from jupeter to a .py file i get the no module named PIL error again.
does this matter when i install pillow it says 'WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)'

Comment: it could be that you only fix the env of your jupyter environment, but your global env is still not having the right module installed.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: you use vritualenv then you can ensure that you are fix that one env and every time you run your code you activate the env.

Answer (score 1):

pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow
resolved my issue